# How yii pass value data in link to the action

Tags: php, yii

I need to get the data from link url to the controller action. Send value from email to my application

```
<a href="http://myweb.com/register?r=Register/ClickVerifyEmail?xxxx=<?php echo xxxx;?>&ssss=<?php echo ssss; ?>">Click me </a>
```

**In controller action**

```
public function actionClickVerifyEmail(){
    $verifycode = $_GET['xxxx'];
    $theid = $_GET['ssss'];

    //others stuff
}
```

**Result is Error: Page Not Found.**

Any suggestion to do that ? or I miss something on my code ? Anyone can help me check ? Thanks

Comment: Your URL given in href myweb.com/register?r=Register/ClickVerifyEmail?xxxx=<?php echo xxxx;?>&ssss=<?php echo ssss; ?>   is WRONG , Try in Yii way <?php echo CHtml::link('Link Text',array('controller/action',
                                         'param1'=>'value1')); ?>

Comment: @ramamoorthy_villi thanks for your reply, but this link is inside the email ... still able to use yii?

Comment: your application is sending this mail . so it build the wrong url . so fix it there.

Comment: @ramamoorthy_villi not send from application is from mail to application

Answer (score 0):

Your URL given in href is wrong , there is two  "?" in the link , so it may breaks .

Try to follow the Yii way link ,

```
<?php echo CHtml::link('Click me',array('Register/ClickVerifyEmail',
                                         'xxxx'=>'value1','ssss'=>'value2')); ?>
```

if you want to send Absolute Url from your application to email . you can build the link by this way .

```
Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('Register/ClickVerifyEmail', array('xxxx'=>'value1','ssss'=>'value2'));
```

if https:

```
Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('Register/ClickVerifyEmail', array('xxxx'=>'value1','ssss'=>'value2'), 'https');
```

Comment: but this link is inside the email ... still able to use yii?

Comment: No , you cannot . Your application is sending this email with wrong Url . So fix it there.

Comment: this link is inside the email has been sent ... how to add Yii inside?? u know what I mean ?

Comment: I tried the example 1 ... the in front the url why added index.php ?

Comment: I want to send Absolute Url from my email to application

Answer (score 0):

```
Yii::app()->createUrl('controller/action' , array('key1' => 'value1'));
```

echo above to get your desired urls any where you need

Comment: but this link is inside the email ... still able to use yii?

Comment: is Email generated by yii??, when you are making that email, you should make that url, then any where it is accessible, right?

Answer (score 0):

I find my own solution:

```
<a href="http://myweb.com/register?r=Register/ClickVerifyEmail?xxxx=<?php echo xxxx;?>&ssss=<?php echo ssss; ?>">Click me </a>
```

**Delete the render url `register?r=`**:

```
    <a href="http://myweb.com/Register/ClickVerifyEmail?xxxx=<?php echo xxxx;?>&ssss=<?php echo ssss; ?>">Click me </a>
```

**Directly put controller name and action.**

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for another question mark in the URL. The route (**?r=**) you passed is already a variable, so what you need to do is to just use an ampersand (**&**) for the next value you are passing.

**URL**

```
<a href="http://myweb.com/register?r=Register/ClickVerifyEmail&xxxx=<?php echo xxxx;?>&ssss=<?php echo ssss; ?>">Click me </a>
```

**CONTROLLER ACTION**

```
public function actionClickVerifyEmail($xxxx, $ssss){
//So no need for $_GET['xxxx'];
//Just use $xxxx as a variable where needed
//e.g.
$a = $xxxx;
```