# how to send data via a url in GridView in yii 2

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

```
'label'=>'bla',
       'format' => 'raw',
   'value'=>function ($data) {
         return Html::a(Html::encode("Subscribe"),'site/index');
```

I have the above code and I want to send an integer or any data with the link. How can I do that? I did search and all I found was broken answer in two pieces

1. How to create link in gridview in yii 2
2. How to send data with link

There is no answer for how to send data with link created in the gridview .. Like the above given code.

for (1.) I found the above mentioned code

for (2.) I

`Yii::app()->createUrl('controller/action' , array('key1' => 'value1'));`

or

```
<?php echo CHtml::link('Click me',array('Register/ClickVerifyEmail',
                                     'xxxx'=>'value1','ssss'=>'value2')); ?>
```

and some others on this post

[Other anwsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26857607/how-yii-pass-value-data-in-link-to-the-action)

So does anyone know how to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

The  `CHtml::link('Click me',array('Register/ClickVerifyEmail'.....` in for yii1 and not for Yii2

the first one is correct and you can  try with this (using a `test` action) :

```
 'value' => function () {
 return Html::a(Html::encode("Subscribe"),'site/test?id='.$value1);
}
```

in the controller you get the value in this way

```
public function actionTest($id){
  ....
   find($id);
  ...
}
```

**NB** the name of the parameter in controller ($id) and the name in link  (id) must match.

Comment: and how would I retrieve that value in controller ? in the function ?

Comment: there is only one problem left .... there are lot of functions in the controller.. how would the link know which function to call and pass the value to .. I am a little new to yii mvc

Comment: "site/test" means, that site is a controller and test is an action name. 
It's easier to create links with UrlHelper. Check this link
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl.html#to()-detail

Comment: @PatrykRadziszewski I wrote site/actionIndex in the code given in answer but it says url not found. please help... actionIndex being the name of function in my controller for the view

Comment: just "site/index" Yii will recognize that it's an action

Comment: @PatrykRadziszewski awsome.. I am just getting one last error is that when I click the link it says parameter is missing : id as in site/test?id='.$value1.. it is not recognizing the sent varibale .. how to fix that ?

Comment: I am using this code

Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('event/create',array('event_id' => $data->id)))

Comment: it's because You sent event_id. 
As scaisEdge said: "the name of the parameter in controller ($id) and the name in link (id) must match."
it should looks like "public function actionCreate($event_id)"